# db.SaveChanges() Exploding with Transaction Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

The following method is causing the FIRST `db.SaveChanges()` to throw an exception:
(New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.)

```
protected void btnInsertDependencies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (icmsEntities db = new icmsEntities())
    {
        var divisions = db.Divisions;
        foreach (var division in divisions)
        {
            var dlc_sectors = db.Sectors.Where(s => s.Website.division_id == division.division_id).DistinctBy(s => s.name).ToList();
            foreach (var sector in dlc_sectors)
            {
                dlc_Sector dlc_sector = new dlc_Sector
                {
                    name = sector.name,
                    division_id = sector.Website.division_id
                };

                db.dlc_Sectors.AddObject(dlc_sector);

                var dlc_products = db.Products.Where(p => p.Sectors
                    .Any(s => s.Website.division_id == dlc_sector.division_id && s.name == dlc_sector.name))
                    .DistinctBy(p => p.name).ToList();

                foreach (var product in dlc_products.ToList())
                {
                    var dlc_product = db.dlc_Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.name == product.name);
                    if (dlc_product == null)
                    {
                        dlc_product = new dlc_Product { name = product.name };
                        db.dlc_Products.AddObject(dlc_product);
                    }
                    dlc_product.dlc_Sectors.Add(dlc_sector);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The first `db.SaveChanges()` is to make sure that a new product having the same name does not get inserted again.

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

### Worked for me:

```
                    var Local = db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added)
                        .Where(es => es.Entity is dlc_Product).Select(es => es.Entity as dlc_Product);
                    var dlc_product = db.dlc_Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.name == product.name)
                        ?? Local.SingleOrDefault(p => p.name == product.name);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's MoreLinq `DistinctBy` returning IEnumerable... Just sayin'

Comment: Why don't you just call `SaveChanges()` once and let the database handle duplicate names.

Comment: How would I let the database do that? Wouldn't that return exceptions also ? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this occurs, but the first `SaveChanges()` would not be necessary if you also checked the `Local` collection of `db.dlc_Products`:

```
foreach (var product in dlc_products.ToList())
{
   var dlc_product = db.dlc_Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.name == product.name)
       ?? db.dlc_Products.Local.SingleOrDefault(p => p.name == product.name);
    ...
}
```

New objects are added to the `Local` collection.

Note that `db.dlc_Products.Join(db.dlc_Products.Local)` looks more efficient, but it does not compile, and the other way around it queries the whole `db.dlc_Products` for each call.

Comment: Nice, I was trying to figure out a way to check it locally instead of hitting the database, never knew `Local` existed. Will try now.

Comment: OK, this is ObjectContext, no DbContext. It is a bit harder to query the local objects in an ObjectContext. How to do that is shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781018.aspx), see paragraph DbSet.Local.

Comment: Of course you can also simply use a list object to store the new products you added so far.